# How to solve scrolling in list view when gridview as a child?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-layout

How to solve the scrolling issue in flutter layout when adding gridview inside listview. 
in android studio java we use NestedScrollView to solve this type of issue
 What is the solution for flutter?
I need to scrolling continues with out any problem with listview with custom view and gridview.
Now then gridview  is only allowing to scroll gridview 
if i scroll grid view then top imageview is not scrolling .How to solve this issue?

```
body: 
    ListView(
  children: <Widget>[
    new Image.network("https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg"),
    Container(
    height: 300.0,
    child: GridView.count(
      crossAxisCount: 3,
      childAspectRatio: .6,
      children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
    ),
  ) 
  ],
)
```

[image]

After adding @deniss answer
[image]

SOLVED
[image]

Comment: Do you want to turn off the scrolling of the GridView?

Comment: no, i need my grid view scrolling and banner view and other views

Comment: Hi, pls check the updated answer

Comment: check update in my question @Dennis

Comment: @Midhilaj check my edited answer... Its for you.

Comment: @Govaadiyo Thank you very mush

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of use `ListView` you should use Column Widget Like below.

```
    body: 
        Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container (
         height: 150.0, // Set as you want
        child: Image.network("https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg")),
        Container(
        height: 300.0,
        child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: .6,
          children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
        ),
      ) 
      ],
    )

Because of `GridView` itself has scroll effect.
```

**EDITED:**

```
Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Container(
          child: ListView(
            children: <Widget>[
              Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Image.network(
                        "https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg"),
                  ),
                  ConstrainedBox(
                    constraints: BoxConstraints(
                      minHeight: 80, // Set as you want or you can remove it also.
                      maxHeight: double.infinity,
                    ),
                    child: Container(
                      child: GridView.count(
                        crossAxisCount: 3,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                        childAspectRatio: .6,
                        children: _list.map((p) => ProductManagment(p)).toList(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

You have to use `ConstrainedBox` with set `maxHeight: double.infinity` and  `GridView.count` set `shrinkWrap: true,`. and remove container height 300.

Also if you want to change

```
 Container(
                    height: 200,
                    child: Image.network(
                        "https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg"),
                  ),
```

To Just

```
 Image.network("https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg")
```

Than you can change it.

Comment: What if the image covers the whole screen? How will you scroll to the GridView??

Comment: Warp image as child of  to container and give specific height of that container.

Comment: Bad idea, what if I want the image to be full screen or as long as it can? That's not an elegant solution. What if I want 3 more images above grid view????????

Comment: I think Image has Fit property that we can set and If you want images with grid then defiantly you have to apply fix height. That my opinion.. If you have best solution then pls provide us. It will improve my knowledge too.. i'm also new at Flutter

Comment: Kindly check my answer.

Comment: @Dennis - did you check output when we add image as bottom of appbar ?

Comment: check my edited answer and let me know if any mistake ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. However, I did not want the issue of `Overflowed by...` that comes with a Column/Row and instead added `physics: ScrollPhysics()` to my `GridView.count` to resolve this issue. Found my answer from [this response](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19205#issuecomment-404028518) to a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

**use this**

```
   child: GridView.count(
    crossAxisCount: 2,
    crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
    shrinkWrap: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
      return Center(
        child: new Column(
          children: [
            new Expanded(
              child: SelectCard(choice: choices[index]),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }),
  ));
```

and full code for better explanation

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

var url = "https://miro.medium.com/max/2160/1*9JzKFil-Xsip742fdxDqZw.jpeg";

class Dashboard extends StatefulWidget {
  _Dashboard createState() => _Dashboard();
}

Widget _buildAvatar(BuildContext context, Orientation orientation) {
  return Container(
    height: 300.0,
    color: Colors.blue,
    child: Center(
      child: CircleAvatar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        child: Text('RR'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

Widget _buildFields(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      child: GridView.count(
        crossAxisCount: 2,
        crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
        shrinkWrap: true,
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        children: List.generate(choices.length, (index) {
          return Center(
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                new Expanded(
                  child: SelectCard(choice: choices[index]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        }),
      ));
}

class _Dashboard extends State<Dashboard> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return OrientationBuilder(builder: (context, orientation) {
      return ListView(
        children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            height: 200,
            child: Image.network(
                "https://www.gizbot.com/img/2013/11/23-weekend-deals-top-10-latest-smartphones.jpg"),
          ),
          _buildFields(context),
        ],
      );
    });
  }
}

class Choice {
  const Choice({this.title, this.icon});
  final String title;
  final IconData icon;
}

const List<Choice> choices = const <Choice>[
  const Choice(title: 'Home', icon: Icons.home),
  const Choice(title: 'Contact', icon: Icons.contacts),
  const Choice(title: 'Map', icon: Icons.map),
  const Choice(title: 'Phone', icon: Icons.phone),
  const Choice(title: 'Camera', icon: Icons.camera_alt),
  const Choice(title: 'Setting', icon: Icons.settings),
  const Choice(title: 'Album', icon: Icons.photo_album),
  const Choice(title: 'WiFi', icon: Icons.wifi),
];

class SelectCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const SelectCard({Key key, this.choice}) : super(key: key);
  final Choice choice;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final TextStyle textStyle = Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1;
    return Container(
      child: GridView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
          crossAxisCount: 1,
          childAspectRatio: 1,
        ),
        itemBuilder: (contxt, indx) {
          return Card(
            elevation: 4,
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            color: Colors.white70,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
              child: Container(
                width: 4,
                child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Container(
                          child: new Icon(
                            choice.icon,
                            color: Colors.black,
                            size: 50.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        flex: 2,
                      ),
                      new Expanded(
                        child: new Container(
                            margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 12),
                            child: new Text(
                              choice.title,
                              style:
                                  TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
                            )),
                        flex: 1,
                      ),
                    ]),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```